# C++ : Can't pass generic function to another one as a parameter

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, compare, function-pointers

I want to pass multiple compare functions to the selection sort function as shown below but i get the fallowing error :

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'sort' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(int,int)' to 'bool *(__cdecl *)(T,T)'   c:\users\milad\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\functionpass\functionpass\passcompare.cpp  49  FunctionPass
```

Code :

```
bool integerCompare (int a , int b)
{
    return(a<b);
}
bool charCompare (char a , char b)
{
    return(a<b);
}
bool stringCompare (string a , string b)
{
    if(a.compare(b)<0) return true;
    else return false;
}
template <class T>
void sort(T x[], int n , bool(*whichCompare(T,T))) // n=size of the array
{
    for (int pass=0; pass<n-1; pass++) {
        int potentialSmallest = pass;  
        for (int i=pass+1; i<n; i++) {
            if ((*whichCompare)(x[i],x[potentialSmallest])) {
                potentialSmallest = i;
            }
        }

        int temp = x[pass];
        x[pass] = x[potentialSmallest];
        x[potentialSmallest] = temp;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void printArray(T a[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<" "<<a[i];
}
int main()
{
    int intArray[] = {1,7,-8,-14,46,33,4};
    sort <int>(intArray , 7 , integerCompare);
    printArray<int>(intArray,7);
}
```

Comment: use `bool(*whichCompare)(T,T)` instead of `bool(*whichCompare(T,T))`.

Answer (score 7):

You have this:

```
template <class T> void sort(T x[], int n , bool(*whichCompare(T,T)))
{ /*...*/ }
```

The parameter declaration for a pointer to a function returning a `bool` and two arguments of type `T` is wrong. You probably really wanted:

```
template <class T> void sort(T x[], int n , bool (*whichCompare)(T,T))
{ /*...*/ }
```

Although typically functions like these are written like this:

```
template <class T, typename Functor>
void sort(T x[], int n , Functor whichCompare)
{
    // ...
    bool result = whichCompare(x[i], x[potentialSmallest]);
    // ...
}
```

This way, users can not only pass in function pointers, but function *objects* that provides an `operator()()`:

```
struct MyIntegerCompareFunctor
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
};

sort(intArray, 7, MyIntegerCompareFunctor());
sort(intArray, 7, &integerCompare); // Works too
```

Some of the algorithms provided by the C++ standard libraries are written like this.

Comment: +1. And just to point out *why* it is preferable to allow function objects, they can hold state, making them more flexible and powerful, and they are easier for the compiler to inline, so they will often be faster as well.

Comment: +1 More common way to write the code is with the Functor being another template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

See my corrections in the lines that have whichCompare in them.

```
template <class T>
void sort(T x[], int n , bool(*whichCompare)(T,T)) // n=size of the array
{
    for (int pass=0; pass<n-1; pass++) {
        int potentialSmallest = pass;  
        for (int i=pass+1; i<n; i++) {
            if (whichCompare(x[i],x[potentialSmallest])) {
                potentialSmallest = i;
            }
        }

        int temp = x[pass];
        x[pass] = x[potentialSmallest];
        x[potentialSmallest] = temp;
    }
}
```

You could also templatise the function itself thus:

```
template< typename T, typename Pred >
void sort( T x[], int n, Pred whichCompare )
{ // etc.
}
```

I used to do this initially just because it was easier but also allows functors / boost-function/boost-bind etc. to be used with your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

there is a much more sexy solution:

```
bool integerCompare (int a , int b)
{
    return(a<b);
}
bool charCompare (char a , char b)
{
    return(a<b);
}

bool stringCompare (string a , string b)
{
    return (a.compare(b)<0);
}

template <typename T, size_t n >
void sort(T (&x)[n], bool whichCompare (T,T) ) // n=size of the array
{
    for (int pass=0; pass<n-1; pass++) {
        int potentialSmallest = pass;  
        for (int i=pass+1; i<n; i++) {
            if (whichCompare(x[i],x[potentialSmallest])) {
                potentialSmallest = i;
            }
        }

        std::swap(x[pass], x[potentialSmallest]);
    }
}


template <typename T, size_t n>
void printArray(T (&a)[n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<" "<<a[i];
}
int main()
{
    int intArray[] = {1,7,-8,-14,46,33,4};
    sort (intArray, integerCompare);
    printArray(intArray);
}
```